# Have 2 integers, create a given third one using addition/subtraction only

Tags: math

Given 4 integers A,B,D,F. Create F from D using only the below steps:
1. Add A
2. Subtract A
3. Add B
4. Subtract B

The above steps can be performed in any number and in any order. What is the correct algorithmic approach for this?

Comment: seems kind of like a Diophantine equation.

Comment: correct algorithmic approach is first to check that  F-D is divisible by GCD(A,B)

Answer (score 0):

correct algorithmic approach is first to check that F-D is divisible by GCD(A,B)

if it isn't STOP - there is no solution.

Starting at D add A until the result is greater or equal to F

if greater than F subtract B until less than or equal F

if less resume adding A

Done.